# How to extend Entity class in Spring Boot with Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

After couple years Python development trying to learn Spring Boot and Kotlin.

And can't figure out how to extend `Entity` class with `created_at`, `updated_at` columns

I'll try to represent what I looking for using python:

```py
@dataclass
class TableWithTime:
  created_at: datetime
  updated_at: datetime

@dataclass
class TableWithDefaultId:
  id: int

@dataclass
class User(TableWithDefaultId, TableWithTime):
  name: str
```

Here are `TableWithDefaultId` and `TableWithTime` may be called `MixIns`.

When we create `User` instance:

```py
u = User(
  id = 1,
  name = "John",
  created_at = datetime.datetime.now(),
  updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()
)
```

All properties will be included and we will be able to call `u.created_at` for example.

Now I trying to implement same thing with Kotlin and Spring Boot:

```kotlin
@Entity
abstract class TableWithTime(
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    var created_at: Date,
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var updated_at: LocalDateTime
)

@Entity
abstract class TableWithStandardId(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0
)

@Entity
data class User(
    var name: String
): TableWithTime(), TableWithStandardId()
```

The first problem is that IDE saying me:

> No value passed for parameter 'created_at'
> No value passed for parameter 'updated_at'

for `TableWithTime()` class. But I don't want to instantiate `TableWithTime` class and set parameters immediately

The second problem is

> Only one class may appear in a supertype list

And it is not possible to extend `User` class with two super-classes like I did it with Python.

**So the question is**, what is closer and best possible solution to implement common `ID` and `created_at` / `updated_at` columns without adding it manually as parameters to every `Entity` class?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

This annotation pretty much tells JPA/Spring that it has shared attributes for other `@Entity` classes. Inside those `@MappedSupperclass`es you work as you normally would, and let Spring do its magic.

```kotlin
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class TableWithTime(
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    var created_at: Date,
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var updated_at: LocalDateTime
)

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class TableWithStandardId(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0
)

@Entity
data class User(
    var name: String
): TableWithTime(), TableWithStandardId() // this is wrong, see updated answer
```

(I'm not familiar with Kotlin, I suggest you double check syntax.)

UPDATE

First of all, I apologize because of my lack of knowledge of Kotlin led me to misread the code. Now checking a bit the language I see my mistake, but I will keep the answer hoping it might give you a push into the right direction. The following code, then, is an interpolation of how we deal with `@MappedSuperclass` in Spring/JPA in Java with what I've read so far of Kotlin. As this is potentially not valid Kotlin, please consider it pseudocode.

If both abstract classes are needed, then you'd need a third abstract class or you'd use interfaces. Since most tables probably use an ID, I'd declare an Interface for `TableWithStandardId` so to have more control over the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

```kotlin
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class TableWithTime {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    var created_at: Date,
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var updated_at: LocalDateTime
}

interface TableWithStandardId {
    var id: Long
}

@Entity
class User (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    override var id: Long = 0,
    var name: String
): TableWithTime(), TableWithStandardId
```

Note that I didn't "declared" the properties of the abstract class in the constructor, but in the class body.

Comment: Hmmm, tried to check [`MappedSuperclass`](https://rennnosukesann.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/29/213732) (sorry for Japanese). But looks like we still have to set default parameters for a parent class or pass these parameters when extending child class (first problem in my question). And second problem is can't be solved with this type of class. Child class may be extended only with one parent class (I have to choose between TableWithTime and TableWithStandardId)

Comment: I just noticed there are MANY things wrong in my answer. I apologize. I tried to give a general direction in my updated answer.